# PHP: Check who had read sent email?

Tags: php

I am sending email to some users and wants to know who had read it, means if some one had read that email then a log file will maintain which contain the email address of that user with date/time/IP.
For this I send a javascript function with the email (html template) which just alert the email address of the user when ever a user opens that email like:

```
for($n=0; $n<sizeof($checkBox); $n++){
        $mail = new PHPMailer();
        $mail->IsHTML(true);
        $mail->Subject = $subject;
        $function = "<script language='javascript'>function stats(emailId){alert(emailId);}</script>";
        $bodyOpen = "<body onload='stats(".$checkBox[$n].");'>"; 
        $msg_body .= $body .= "<table><tr><td>Hello Everyone</td></tr></table></body>";
        $mail->Body = $function.$bodyOpen.$msg_body;
        $mail->WordWrap = 50;
        $mail->FromName = 'Muhammad Sajid';
        $mail->IsMAIL();        
        $mail->From = 'webspot49@gmail.com';
        $mail->AddAddress($checkBox[$n]);
        $sent = $mail->Send();
    }
```

the html template works fine and shows an alert popup on page load but it does not works if I use to send this html template.

And I only want to solve this issue using PHP5.x.x / javascript, no other software or third party tool.
Any help..?

Comment: Offer a monetary reward for email replies.  :-)

Comment: It is not **reliably** possible to know if and when an email was read. There are only options that may work some of the time.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Add Header to email:

```
Disposition-Notification-To: you@yourdomain.com
```

As mentioned above it's not reliable and it's better to do something like this:

```
<img src="http://yourdomain.com/emailreceipt.php?receipt=<email of receiver>" />
```

And log it in a database, although again this is restricted by the email client's ability to show images and sometimes it may even put the mail into junk because it doesn't detect an image... a workaround that would be to actually outputting an image (say your logo) at the end of that script.

Edit:
A quick lookup at the phpmailer class gave me the following:

```
$mail->ConfirmReadingTo = 'yourown@emailaddress.com';
```

but it's the same as the Disposition-Notification-To method above.

Comment: Kindly describe <img src="http://yourdomain.com/emailreceipt.php?receipt=<email of receiver>" /> more, or provide any helpful link..

Comment: I used $mail->ConfirmReadingTo = 'yourown@emailaddress.com';
 but it does not send me a confermation email...   any mistake..?

Comment: As said above the Dispoisition-Notification-To method doesn't work with all email clients.
As for the img tag method, you make a php script that takes in the receipt get variable and process it (store in DB, or whatever you want to do as if the reciever confirmed receipt of email) and if the email client shows the 'image' with the php script as source, it will run the script... to avoid the mail client possibly thinking the link is malicious, you should output a real image at the end of the script

Comment: including an img URL and tracking how many times it was hit is the best way, though sometimes it may not work as most email clients today block images and ask users whether they want to download images or not

Comment: @Populus, I have followed this like method(image with http request). Its working fine with gmail. but not working with outlook.

Comment: @siva The comment I made above clarifies that this method does not always work... Email clients can easily block this particular method by removing the query string when loading the image. You can however also bypass this by storing a hash of the email address, and use the hash as the image filename, to trick the email client. Again, I cannot guarantee that these methods will work with all email clients, or if email clients fixes it...

Answer (score 8):

Send a beacon image in the emails like so

```
<img src='http://www.yourserver.com/beacon.php?email_id=$email_id&email_address=$user_address' style='width:1px;height:1px'>
```

And then use the beacon.php file to log the data.  You will then want to output a 1X1 image with appropriate headers.

**Important note**
 Many popular email clients (such as Gmail) now block external images, so this is by far, not fool proof.

Answer (score 4):

This is next to impossible to do 100% effectively.

1. You could control where the content is stored e.g. http://www.example.com/34hg038g85gb8no84g5 and provide a link in the email to that content, you can then detect when that URL was viewed.
2. Use a method used by MailChimp and other newsletter campaigns, put an invisible image in your email, this image should reside on a  server you control, you can then detect when that image is hit when the user opens the email.

Comment: In that second solution, you'd have to assume the reader doesn't block foreign content.

Comment: Yup, hence not 100% effective

Answer (score 2):

It is not possible by definition.

Answer (score 1):

Mailreaders are not browsers, they don't support javascript. They don't even support proper CSS so dont expect too much. So I honestly don't see any way you can do what you're trying to do

Answer (score 1):

I just add a single line:

```
$dt = date('F \ jS\,\ Y h:i:s a');
for($n=0; $n<sizeof($checkBox); $n++){
   $mail = new PHPMailer();
   $mail->IsHTML(true);
   $mail->Subject = $subject;
   $src = "<img src='msajid.isgreat.org/readmail.php?dt=".$dt."&eid=".$checkBox[$n]."' />";
   $msg_body .= $src .= "<table><tr><td>Hello Everyone</td></tr></table>";
   $mail->Body = $function.$bodyOpen.$msg_body;
   $mail->WordWrap = 50;
   $mail->FromName = 'Muhammad Sajid';
   $mail->IsMAIL();        
   $mail->From = 'webspot49@gmail.com';
   $mail->AddAddress($checkBox[$n]);
   $sent = $mail->Send();
}
```

and in **readmail.php** file simply insert date/time and userid with a check (if not exist with attached date/time) & fixed it only for Gmail, hotmail but not for Yahoo...
Can some one help to also fix for Yahoo....?

Haaaa.
silly mistake just use complete url like:

```
$src = "<img src='http://www.msajid.isgreat.org/readmail.php?dt=".$dt."&eid=".$checkBox[$n]."' />";
```

and it will also work for Yahoo....

Answer (score 1):

While I didn't discover exactly why the simple PHP file wasn't generating the included image (as mentioned in my post 6 hours ago), here is another very complicated way of generating an image file that *wasn't* rejected by my own PHP 5.4.30 web server.

Here is the code that I put into an index.php file within an /email_image/ subdirectory:

```
<?php
$message_id = $_REQUEST['message_id'];

$graphic_http = 'http://mywebsite.com/email_image/message_open_tracking.gif';

$filesize = filesize( 'message_open_tracking.gif' );

header( 'Pragma: public' );
header( 'Expires: 0' );
header( 'Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0' );
header( 'Cache-Control: private',false );
header( 'Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="a_unique_image_name_' . $message_id  . '.gif"' );
header( 'Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary' );
header( 'Content-Length: '.$filesize );
readfile( $graphic_http );
exit;
?>
```

For the image filename, I used the following:

```
http://mywebsite.com/email_image/?message_id=12345
```

Within the email_image folder is also a blank 1x1 gif image named "message_open_tracking.gif".

The index.php file can also be revised to make use of the message_id in order to mark that message as having been read.  If other variables are included within the querystring, such as the recipient's email address, those values can also be used within that index.php file.

Many thanks to Bennett Stone for the following article:
http://www.phpdevtips.com/2013/06/email-open-tracking-with-php-and-mysql/

Comment: above Bennett Stone link is not working @Bryce Morrison

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old thread but I just had to respond... for those of us who must consider this, I suggest we put ourselves in the place of the people who have to write the anti-spam software to thwart our efforts.  Detecting a ? or a .php (or other script/binary extension) inside an image tag would be trivial for me as a postulated 'spam assassin' programmer... just as identifying a 1x1 image would be...

I spent 2.5 yrs as National Digital Director for a presidential campaign that raised $20 million *before we even had a candidate* -- here's what I had developed for that campaign:

1. At send time (or before), generate a hash on the TO: email address and store that in the db next to the email address.
2. Use the hash we just generated to modify a small, but plainly visible logo in the email and make a copy of the logo with the hash in the logo file name eg: emxlogox.0FAE7E6.png - refer to that unique image in the email for the logo - make a copy of the logo with the hash name in the filename. This particular logo series only ever appears in targeted mass emails.  Warn crew members not to copy it for other purposes (or to rename it extensively if they do).  The first part of the filename needs to be something that will not appear in the logs in other contexts to speed your parsing and the code you have to craft to sort out false hits.
3. Parse the logs for occurrences of the logo being requested, and extract the hash from the filename to match back against the one email address. And your parsing program can also get the IP address and the time delta it took for them to get and open the email so you can identify highly responsive recipients and the ones who took a week to open the email.  Do a geo-lookup on the IP and see if you get a match with the location you already have, and/or start recording their travel patterns (or proxy use patterns). Geo deltas could also be identifying email forwards.

Same hash, of course, is used to record clicks, and also the first and second opt-ins. (Now you have a 'dossier' of multiple opt-ins for responses to those abuse reports and you're protecting your email reputation, too).

This method can also be used to identify who forwards emails to their friends and you ask those 'good forwarders' to join some kind of elite digital volunteer crew, offer them discounts or rewards or whatever is appropriate for your business/project... in essence, that same hash also becomes a referrer code.

You can also ask them to right click on the logo in the email and save it without changing the filename, then post it to 'wherever' (the image should have a memorable, readable, meaningful shortlink on it, not an unreadable  bit.ly shortlink).  You can then use the Google Search API to identify who helped you out in that fashion and thank them or give them rewards...  For this purpose, it helps if the first part of your logo filename is really unique like unsportingly.unique.emxlogox.0FAE7E6.png so you don't have to do millions of Google Search API queries - just search on the unique first part of the filename - and look at the hashes after you get the hits.

You store the links where their copy of the logo appeared in your db to add to your dossier of where on the net they are active and have helped you.

Yes, it's slow and burdensome, but in these days when we say we want to develop a 'relationship' with our email list, it's what you have to do to give individual treatment; identify and reward your friends.  And yes, you end up with millions of those hashed filename images in one directory, but storage is cheap and it's worth it to really have that relationship with your peeps.

Answer (score 0):

You can't add javascript to your emails.
The only solution would be to have only a link in the email, and the message on the server, Then you'd able to know that the message itself has been viewed.

Comment: Well, you can, if your objective is to get flagged as spam as soon as possible.

Answer (score 0):

Embedding a user specific image (1px blank might be good) in the email and record whether it is hot or not is a fair solution. But the problem Gmail like client block external images by default.

Answer (score 0):

Please refer [RFC-3798](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3798) for more details about MDN.

Answer (score 0):

As the last post was awhile back, I am uncertain as to whether this method still works.

I tested this method on a server running PHP 5.4.30, and it does not seem to output an image.

This is some very simple code:

```
<img src="http://theservername.com/myaccount_email_read_offline.php">
```

Note that I removed the querystring and any additional code from this image.

Opening up that separate page, myaccount_email_read_offline.php did display the image.

However, trying to include the image by including a PHP file in its place did not work.

Answer (score 0):

As some of the other answers have mentioned, it is possible to detect when a recipient has opened a message, if the message contains a remotely hosted image (and the recipient's mail client is set to open remotely hosted images).

[UltraSMTP](https://www.ultrasmtp.com/) is an outgoing SMTP mail server that inserts a remotely hosted image in each outgoing message sent through the server, for this purpose.

See https://www.ultrasmtp.com/kb/developers.php for sample code for sending mail through UltraSMTP from a PHP script (using PHPMailer).