# Tracking mails php

Tags: php, email

how can i track mails to detect if it is opened or not and click links on it 
using mail function

```
   $to=$mail['mail_to'] = $_POST['to'];
$subject=$mail['subject'] = validate($_POST['subject']);
$mail['message'] = makeLinks(validate($_POST['message']));
if ($add->add('mails', $mail)) {
    $row = $se->get_last_Row('mails');

    $message = $mail['message'];
           $headers = "From: $from  <" . $from . ">\r\n";
    $headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
    $headers .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8\r\n";
    $send = mail($to, $subject, $message,$headers);
```

Comment: `mail` function just sends email. That's all it does.

Comment: It's too broad, ask about specific problem or error that you can't handle and it's not yet answered on SO.

Comment: @u_mulder which  function or technique like mail function to do tracking

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP: Check who had read sent email?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4603850/php-check-who-had-read-sent-email)

Answer (score 0):

Most systems work with a little image which is in the (html) e-mail.
On your server you receive a request for the image, and this way you can count the read e-mails.

Comment: But Gmail and yahoo consider its src banned,